# ArrayAdapter : Json data to be sent to spinner

Tags: android, json, android-arrayadapter, android-spinner, arrays

Hi I have created an activity which pulls data from json format text and displays in a spinner view. But im a little confused with the last part. The contactList is a ArrayList type, ArrayAdapter is not accepting contactList as its arugument.
Is
Here's my code

```
 public class RegisterForEventActivity extends Activity {

        private static String url = "http://10.0.2.2/Contacts.txt";
        private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
        private static final String TAG_CONTACTS = "contacts";

        JSONArray jsonArray = null;

        Spinner areaspinner;

        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.register_layout);


         // Hashmap for ListView
            ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

                // Creating JSON Parser instance
                JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

                // getting JSON string from URL
                JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);

                try {
                    // Getting Array of Contacts
                    jsonArray = json.getJSONArray(TAG_CONTACTS);

                    final String[] array_spinner = new String[jsonArray.length()]; 

                    // looping through All Contacts
                    for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){

                        JSONObject c = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                        // Storing each json item in variable
                        String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);

                        // creating new HashMap
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                        map.put(TAG_NAME, name);


                        // adding HashList to ArrayList
                        contactList.add(map);

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = 
                                new ArrayAdapter<String> (this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, contactList);       
                        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                        areaspinner.setAdapter(adapter);
                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I figured it out!

```
sp=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);

     // Hashmap for ListView


            // Creating JSON Parser instance
            JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

            // getting JSON string from URL
            JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
            System.out.println("Hello");
            try {
                // Getting Array of Contacts
                jsonArray = json.getJSONArray(TAG_CONTACTS);

                final String[] items = new String[jsonArray.length()]; 

                // looping through All Contacts
                for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){

                    JSONObject c = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    // Storing each json item in variable

                    String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);


                    items[i]=c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                    System.out.println("Hello events "+items);
                }

                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = 
                        new ArrayAdapter<String> (this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, items);       
                adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                sp.setAdapter(adapter);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Answer (score 3):

This is because you are passing a list of `HashMap`, and not an array of `String`. Make an array of `String`, add your contact data in it and pass it to the array.

instead of using this

```
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
```

use this

```
      ArrayList<String> contactList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. If you want to store extra information other than a simple string you are going to need to use a different Adapter. (such as a key and a value)

Comment: Answer is correct ? but its not showing accepted sign .
yeah right in that case you have to change the collection type and adapter type too

Comment: how to solve this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29446088/how-to-get-spinner-values-in-textview