# left and right navigation to viewpager not working

Tags: android, android-viewpager, viewpagerindicator

I am using view pager in my app,viewpager is working perfect but i want to add viewpagerindicator,following is my snippet code and xml of ui design can any one tell me what is issue?thanks in advance.............

```
 public class Test_Pager extends Activity{
private String strtd;
String[] imgStr;
ImageView imageView;
ArrayList<String> userImgArrayList;
String[] myURLs;
/*country list*/
JSONArray country_list=null;
private ServiceHandler sh;
private String jsonStr;
private JSONObject jsonObj;
private String user_img;
private String user_pro;
private static String PROFILE_VIEW_URL = "";
private static final String USER_IMG="product_images";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.test_pagerss);
    userImgArrayList = getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("user_images");
    ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
       ImageAdapter adapter = new ImageAdapter(this);
       viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
      // TitlePageIndicator titleIndicator = (TitlePageIndicator) findViewById(R.id.titles);
      // titleIndicator.setViewPager(viewPager);
       leftss=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.lefticonsss);
       rightss=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.righticonsss); 

     imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.full_image_view);
     PROFILE_VIEW_URL="";
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new   StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    sh = new ServiceHandler();

        // Making a request to url and getting response
        jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(PROFILE_VIEW_URL, ServiceHandler.GET);

        Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);

     try {
         jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);


             /*proview_business = jsonObj.getString(PROFILE_VIEW_BUSINESS);
             proview_subcat = jsonObj.getString(PROFILE_VIEW_SUB_CATAGORY);
             proview_mainpro = jsonObj.getString(PROFILE_VIEW_MAINPRODUCTS);
             proview_expr = jsonObj.getString(PROFILE_VIEW_EXPERIENCE);
             proview_cmpname = jsonObj.getString(PROFILE_VIEW_COMPANYNAME);
             proview_website = jsonObj.getString(PROFILE_VIEW_WEBSITE);*/

            // user_img=jsonObj.getString(USER_IMG);



            user_img=jsonObj.getString(USER_IMG);
            user_img = "";
            userImgArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();//declare userImgArrayList globally like ArrayList<String> userImgArrayList;
            JSONArray picarray = jsonObj.getJSONArray(USER_IMG);
            for(int i=0;i< picarray.length();i++)
            {
                user_img = picarray.getString(i);
                userImgArrayList.add(user_img);
                Log.d("mylog", "curent  pro pic  = " + user_img);
            }


     } catch (JSONException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
leftss.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(+1,true);
            }
        });
}
public class ImageAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
     Context context;
      ImageAdapter(Context context)
     {
     this.context=context;
     }
      @Override
      public int getCount() {
      return USER_IMG.length();
      }

      @Override
        public void destroyItem(View container, int position, Object object) {
             ((ViewPager) container).removeView((View) object);
        }
     @Override
     public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
     return view == ((ImageView) object);
     }

     @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
            ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
            int padding = context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(
                    R.dimen.activity_horizontal_margin);
            imageView.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);
            //imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
            //Picasso.with(context).load(userImgArrayList.get(position)).into(imageView);
            Picasso.with(context).load(userImgArrayList.get(position)).resize(200, 200) .into(imageView);

            /*for(int i=0; i<myURLs.length;i++)
            { 

                try {
                    url = new URL(myURLs[i]);
                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                try {
                    bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                 imageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);
            }
            */
            // imageView.setImageURI(Uri.parse(imgStr[position]));
            ((ViewPager) container).addView(imageView, 0);
            return imageView;
        }
     }

  }
```

Myxml

```
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:background="@android:color/black"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
>



     <ImageView 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"

   android:src="@drawable/arrow"
   android:rotation="180"
    android:id="@+id/lefticonsss"
    />


  <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
  android:id="@+id/view_pager"
  android:layout_width="150dp"
  android:layout_height="150dp"

   />

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/full_image_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"

    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>


    <ImageView 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/arrow"

    android:id="@+id/righticonsss"
    />



    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Post your xml view of this layout

Comment: I don't see any ViewPagerIndicator class in your xml. Please follow [this sample](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ViewPagerIndicator/blob/master/sample/res/layout/simple_icons.xml) to make it work.

Comment: why to add indicator?cant i change images of view pager,by simply click on left or right imageviews?

Comment: i want something like this,if user click on left imageview then image of view pager will change

Comment: That is a bad user experience imo. Why would you want a clicking event to change the image when you can just swipe the viewpager left or right? Nonetheless, you can achieve what you want by rearranging your xml layout and set onclick listener to the left/right imageviews.

Comment: i already set that..but image is not changing

Comment: Post your error log. I see `viewPager.setCurrentItem(+1,true);` is not a correct syntax. You should use incremental variable instead of +1.

Comment: there isno error in logcat,but image of view pager should change...see this link i am trying same layout http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25157067/left-right-arrow-indicators-over-a-viewpager

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75360/discussion-between-chris-and-aimanb).

Answer (score 0):

I use this library https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip

Summary :

1.do this in your `onCreate`

```
// Initialize the ViewPager and set an adapter
ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
pager.setAdapter(new TestAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));

// Bind the tabs to the ViewPager
PagerSlidingTabStrip tabs = (PagerSlidingTabStrip) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
tabs.setViewPager(pager);
```

2. (Optional) If you use an `OnPageChangeListener` with your `ViewPager` you should set it in the `Widget` rather than on the `ViewPager` directly.

   `tabs.setOnPageChangeListener(mPageChangeListener);`

Comment: yes but I am simply swiping images..not activities..so will it works?

Comment: i edit my question and took imageview for left and right..can you check?..i vote up

Answer (score 0):

Hello I see your update code you are trying to use the TitlePageIndicator. I assume that you did implement the `com.jakewharton.android.viewpagerindicator.TitlePageIndicator`

I have updated your code please see below the modified code.

In you `PagerAdapter` make sure your did `override the getTitle(int position)` method, you have to provide the correct data source to your page adapter. 
getTitle(int position) find the title text from given data source.

```
public class ImageAdapter extends PagerAdapter implements TitleProvider
{ 
    private final Context context;

    public ImageAdapter( Context context )
    { 
        this.context = context;
    } 


    @Override 
    public String getTitle( int position )
    { 
        return userImgArrayList.get(position);
    } 


    @Override 
    public int getCount() 
    { 
        return userImgArrayList.size();
    } 


    @Override 
    public Object instantiateItem( View pager, final int position )
    { 
          ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
          int padding = context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.activity_horizontal_margin);
          imageView.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);
          Picasso.with(context).load(userImgArrayList.get(position)).resize(200, 200) .into(imageView);
          ((ViewPager) container).addView(imageView, 0);
          return imageView;
    } 


    @Override 
    public void destroyItem( View pager, int position, Object view )
    { 
        ( (ViewPager) pager ).removeView( (ListView) view );
    } 


    @Override 
    public boolean isViewFromObject( View view, Object object )
    { 
        return view == ((ImageView) object);
    } 

}
```

Let me know if you any further query. thank you

Comment: Let me know what you want to display in your title page adapter. currently i see in your code your array list contain the image path. if you use that array list your page title will display with the image URL path.

Comment: still it says TitleProvider cannot be resolved to a type

Comment: Are you used jake-whartons-viewpageindicator  then @Overide errors can be solved simply by doing the following:

Right click Project > Properties

Java Compilers > click 'Enable project specific settings' and set Compiler level to 1.6

Click 'Apply'

Comment: do i need to add any external jar?cuz i did not add any external jar yet

Comment: My concern is for TitlePageIndicator which library are you using can you just tell me?

Comment: i did not add any external library..i have just same android_support_v4

Comment: can you tell i added two imageview

Comment: can you tell me why did you hide the title page adapter & put the two image view? what did you wish to achieve?.

Comment: i did not hide pager..i simply put two images,one is left of pager,and one is right of pager..so user will click on left image and right image to change the view of the pager images..getting my point?

Comment: then use the viewPager.setCurrentItem(int index), where index is the your position on click of left and right button.

Comment: index is your image view of array list index. you have to make sure that index should not grater than the size of your array list.

Comment: but how can i predict how many images will come? because i am getting images from server

Comment: i tried this way viewPager.setCurrentItem(userImgArrayList.indexOf(imageView));....but its not working

Answer (score 0):

`ViewPagerIndicator` of [Jake Wharton](http://jakewharton.com/) is a cusomized `View` which is no difference from other views. So you can use it just like any other `View`s. Of course, `ViewPagerIndicator` has some customized attributes of its own, like [attrs](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ViewPagerIndicator/blob/master/library/res/values/vpi__attrs.xml). Take your snippet for example, I think you did well.

PS:Try this:

```
<LinearLayout 
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/lnr11"
android:orientation="vertical"
>
<com.viewpagerindicator.TitlePageIndicator
 android:id="@+id/titles"
  android:layout_height="30dp"
  android:layout_width="match_parent" />

  <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
  android:id="@+id/view_pager"
  android:layout_width="150dp"
  android:layout_height="150dp"
   />

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/full_image_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/></LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Take a look again at what I re-edit, and show me some feedback.

Comment: Then I recommend you to re-check your `ImageAdapter`.

Comment: i edit my question and took imageview for left and right..can you check?..i vote up